# Norms of higher order Lp spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, definition, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

Given $v\in L^p(\Omega)$, $v$'s norm is defined by
$$
\lVert v\rVert_{L^p(\Omega)} = \left[\int_\Omega |v|^p dx \right]^{1/p}
$$

How is $v$'s norm defined if $v\in L^p(\Omega)^d$?

In other words, $v$ is not a scalar, but a vector field over $\Omega$. I saw this denoted as $L^p(\Omega)^d$ in some publications, where $d$ is the dimension.

**EDIT:**

I did a bit of thinking, and following @herb steinberg's comment, came up with something. I don't have a mathematician's education, and I could use some constructive criticism.

Following Marsden and Hughes' *Mathematical Foundations of Elasticity*, Definition 2.2,

> Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set and let $x\in\Omega$.
>   The **tangent space** to $\Omega$ at $x$ is simply the vector space
>   $\mathbb{R}^n$ regarded as vectors emanating from $x$; this tangent
>   space is denoted $$T_x\Omega = \{\mathbb{R}^n, x \in \Omega \}$$  The
>   **tangent bundle** of $\Omega$ is the product $$T\Omega = \Omega\times\mathbb{R}^n \quad(\text{or}\;\; \Omega\times T_x\Omega)$$
>   consisting of pairs $(x,v)$ of base points $x$ and
>   tangent vectors at $x$.

So when I say *a vector field over $\Omega$*, I mean $v\in T\Omega$.

Also, let

$$\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle: T_x\Omega\times T_x\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$$

denote the **inner product at the tangent space** of $x$. The tangent space is then equipped with the **norm**
$$|v|= v \mapsto \sqrt{\langle v,v\rangle}$$

Thus I can extend the original definition of the Lp spaces to account for vector fields. For vector fields $v  \in T\Omega$, the vectors at every point belong to a tangent space such that $v(x)\in T_x\Omega$. Then $L^p(T\Omega)$ is the space equipped with the norm

$$
\lVert v\rVert_{L^p(T\Omega)} 
= \left[\int_\Omega |v(x)|^p dx \right]^{1/p}
= \left[\int_\Omega {\langle v(x),v(x) \rangle}^{p/2} dx \right]^{1/p}
$$

Definitions of Sobolev norms can follow analogically. Do you see a problem with this derivation?

Comment: Do you mean $\Omega^d$?

Comment: @JackyChong I edited the question with more info.

Comment: You need to start with a definition of |v|.

Comment: @herbsteinberg would you kindly look at what I added to the question?

Answer (score 2):

Naively, we have

\begin{align}
\| v\|_{L^p(\Omega)^d} = \sum^d_{j=1} \|v_j\|_{L^p(\Omega)}.
\end{align}
Since $d$ is finite, then we could also use
\begin{align}
\| v\|_{L^p(\Omega)^d} = \left(\sum^d_{j=1} \|v_j\|_{L^p(\Omega)}^p\right)^{1/p}.
\end{align}
since all finite dimensional norms are equivalent.

Comment: would you kindly look at what I added to the question?

Comment: Inner product is usually defined only for p=2.  In general (u,v) would be defined for $u \in L^p\ and \ v\in L^q$ where 1/p+1/q=1.